# Sort with maximum of given swaps

Tags: sorting, graph, swap, minimum

I'm solving a problem which requires to sort an array. An array with size n can contain elements from 1 to n. 
We are given an array and m number of swaps. we have to sort that array by using given swaps and own swap, in such a way we use minimum of own swaps...
Example..
Array 3 1 4 2
Given swaps 1 2
Here first we can perform given swap...array become 1 3 4 2 now we can use own swaps 2 ,4 and 3, 4...(1,2 and 3,4 are indexes)
So answer here is 2 because only own swaps are counted and we need to minimise it